# YQL returns application/javascript even when format=json is requested

Tags: javascript, json, spring, spring-boot, yql

I am trying to make a REST call to YQL in a Spring Boot application.  Even when I set 'format=json', the call returns 'application/javascript' which results in this message:

org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.dilteam.research.YqlQueryResult] and content type [application/javascript;charset=utf-8]

Here's the method (processTicker) & the associated class (YqlQueryResult):

```
public void processTicker(String ticker) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String query = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%3D'YHOO'&format=json&callback=?";
    YqlQueryResult qr = restTemplate.getForObject(query, YqlQueryResult.class);
    System.out.println("result" + qr.results);
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class YqlQueryResult {
    public String results;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RestTemplate` doesn't know how to read an `application/javascript` response. Assuming that `application/javascript` is actually JSON, you can fix your problem by adding an appropriately configured converter to your `RestTemplate`:

```
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(new MediaType("application", "javascript")));
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(javascriptConverter);
```

Comment: new MediaType("application/javascript") didn't work, so I changed to:

new MediaType("application", "javascript")

Now getting:  Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('/' (code 47)): maybe a (non-standard) comment? (not recognized as one since Feature 'ALLOW_COMMENTS' not enabled for parser)
 

The returned JSON has this:  /**/v({"query":{.....

Comment: To get around the 'COMMENTS' problem, added following line but now it returns a Null object:

converter.getObjectMapper().configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_COMMENTS, true);

Comment: The reason I am getting 'Null' is that the table 'yahoo.finance.quotes' is no longer available on YQL.  Weird.  May be Yahoo! changed it's policy!  Closing this issue.  Thanks Andy for the pointer.